# How to use User's property as default value while in the Create Page of Post?

Tags: laravel-nova

Let's say User has a property named 'a_property' , and Post belongs to User. When adding a Post in the create page (which the new Post's user 
automatically set to the selected User), how can I use the User's a_property as default value of Post's b_value?

Comment: Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

Use mutator
https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators

In Your Post model write function like this, adjust naming

```
public function setBValueAttribute($value)
{
   $this->attributes['b_value'] = $this->user->a_property;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

```
BelongsTo::make('Post')
    ->displayUsing(function ($post) {
  return $post->user->a_property;
}),`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `newModel` function to your nova resource class:

```php
<?php
use App\Post;

public static function newModel(): Post
{
    $model = parent::newModel();
    $model->a_property = '';

    return $model;
}
```

Please notice that the `newModel()` method is called **before** Nova filled the attributes coming from the request, so we would not get the `$post_id`. We need to use a event observer to fill the value after the model has been created.

[First, create an Observer for `Post` model](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#events)

```sh
$ php artisan make:observer PostObserver --model=Post
```

then we can put the codes in the `created` method

```php
<?php /* file: app/Observers/PostObserver.php */

use App\Post;

public function create(Post $post)
{
    // Assume the relation is `user`:
    $post->a_property = $post->user->a_property;
    $post->save();
}
```

Also this solution can basically solve the problem, it is not a good idea to store the same value on both `User` and `Post` table.